# Google Analytics Create segment without sub domains

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics

My company's analytics is installed on a site with many subdomains and I do not have access to create a filtered property, so I am trying to make a segment for the main site only.

I have tried a segment where: Page starts with mydomain.com but it also still gets all the subdomains.  There are a lot of subdomains because there are unique ones created for each client, so it is hard to list them all as exclusions.

How do I create a regex or filter to exclude all but the main domain and its pages?

```
YES:  mydomain.com
YES:  mydomain.com/*
NO:   clientA.mydomain.com
NO:   clientB.mydomain.com
NO:   clientC.mydomain.com
NO:   clientD.mydomain.com
NO:   clientE.mydomain.com
NO:   clientF.mydomain.com
NO:   app.mydomain.com
NO:   wip.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour you are getting from the segment functionality is as expected. I think you are just misunderstood what it is for.

The functionality is filtering based on **sessions**. In your case when you use segments, it is actually "show me all the pages people have visisted where they've visited at least a page that started with mydomain.com.

It'll be very difficult for you to filter session level data and exclude all subdomain pages.

If You want a report to include only page-level data, then use the Behaviour > content and use the "begins with" filter there.